# Selecting a back date, month and year from the calender control using selenium web driver 2 in java

Tags: java, selenium

[[Calender Control][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ha6t.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ha6t.png)I want to select a back date using the calender control, Please let me know how I can do that ?

I am able to click on the calender control and use the below line but how can I select the year, month and the date? please let me know ?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@onclick, \"showCalendarControl(\'dateOfBirth\')\")]")).click();
```

Also the DOB filed has a validation which says you can select a date which should make an individual more than 18 years of age

Comment: We don't have the HTML to reference so we can't answer your question.

Comment: @Jeff C : What excatly do you want me to provide you which will  be helpful for you to answer my question

Comment: driver.findElement(By.linkText("«")).click(); did the job for me  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In date time calender their will be a button "<" and ">" or "<<" and ">>" click on this button by finding their id or class and you can navigate to that particular month and year of calender and then select the date.

Comment: Yeah.. that worked for me driver.findElement(By.linkText("«")).click();